# SQL query that creates entry in table and assigns to another object

Tags: sql-server

I have a an application that manages material requests for clients. In this application every MaterialRequest must have an address, however, sometimes this does not happen and I have to fix it !

My solution is to create a defaultaddress and assign it to the orders where the AddressId is null.

```
UPDATE MaterialRequest
SET AddressId = INSERT INTO Address(Complement) VALUES ('');
WHERE AddressId is NULL;
```

However, the previous code does not work and I have no idea on how to do something similar in SQL.

How do I do it?

Comment: Which DBMS? sqlserver <> mysql

Comment: Ops, sqlserver. I will fix the tags now !

Comment: You have to do it into two steps.  Insert the Address table, then set AddressId to that new address's id.  Of course, this would leave all NULL addresses pointing to the SAME address Id if you did it in one Update statement like this, which I'm guessing is NOT what you want.  Am I correct in thinking you want to create a row in Address for every row in MaterialRequest that is NULL, and then hook them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it in your query, add a default to the table definition. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype DEFAULT 'default value'
```